# EKS, Windows node. networkPlugin cni failed

Tags: kubernetes

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/windows-support.html, I ran the command, eksctl utils install-vpc-controllers --cluster <cluster_name> --approve

My EKS version is v1.16.3. I tries to deploy Windows docker images to a windows node. I got error below.

Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  31s               kubelet, ip-west-2.compute.internal  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "ab8001f7b01f5c154867b7e" network for pod "mrestapi-67fb477548-v4njs": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "mrestapi-67fb477548-v4njs_ui" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address

```
$ kubectl logs vpc-resource-controller-645d6696bc-s5rhk -n kube-system
I1010 03:40:29.041761       1 leaderelection.go:185] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/vpc-resource-controller...
I1010 03:40:46.453557       1 leaderelection.go:194] successfully acquired lease kube-system/vpc-resource-controller
W1010 23:57:53.972158       1 reflector.go:341] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20180910083459-2cefa64ff137/tools/cache/reflector.go:99: watch of *v1.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 1480444 (1515040)
```

It complains too old resource version. How do I upgrade the version?

Comment: What version of the vpc-resource-controller do you use?

Comment: $ kubectl logs vpc-resource-controller-645d6696bc-s5rhk -n kube-system
I1010 03:40:29.041761       1 leaderelection.go:185] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/vpc-resource-controller...
I1010 03:40:46.453557       1 leaderelection.go:194] successfully acquired lease kube-system/vpc-resource-controller
W1010 23:57:53.972158       1 reflector.go:341] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20180910083459-2cefa64ff137/tools/cache/reflector.go:99: watch of *v1.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 1480444 (1515040)

Comment: that part does not describe a related problem, I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I removed the windows nodes, re-created windows nodes with different instance type. But, it did not work.
2. Removed windows nodes group, re-created windows nodes group. It did not work.
3. Finally, I removed entire EKS cluster, re-created eks cluster. The command, kubectl describe node <windows_node> gives me the output below.

```
  vpc.amazonaws.com/CIDRBlock           0         0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/ENI                 0         0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address  1         1
```

Deployed windows-server-iis.yaml. It works as expected. The root cause of the problem is mystery.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this I would...

1. First list the components to make sure they're running:

```
$kubectl get pod -n kube-system | grep vpc
vpc-admission-webhook-deployment-7f67d7b49-wgzbg   1/1     Running   0          38h
vpc-resource-controller-595bfc9d98-4mb2g           1/1     Running   0          29
```

2. If they are running check their logs

```
kubectl logs <vpc-yadayada> -n kube-system
```

3. Make sure the instance type you are using has [enough available IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI) per ENI because in the Windows world only one ENI is used and is limited to the max available IP's per ENI minus one for the Primary IP address. I have run into this error before where I have exceeded the number of IP's available to my ENI.
4. Confirm that the selector of your pod is right

```
nodeSelector:
  kubernetes.io/os: windows
  kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
```

As an anecdote, I have done the steps mentioned under the `To enable Windows support for your cluster with a macOS or Linux client` section of the doc you linked on a few clusters to date, and they have worked well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe I run into the problem you described. I removed and re-created the node group a few times. But, it does not help. How to figure out the instance type I am using has enough available IPs? And, how to increase the IPs limits?

Comment: What instance type are you using?  I don’t think you can increase the max IPs allowed by the ENI

Comment: My instance type was m5.large. I tried m5.xlarge and m1.xlarge. None of them works. I removed the node group, re-created the node group with the new instance type. But, no luck.

Comment: I would check the logs of the two components i mentioned in step 1 and I would confirm that your test pod is getting correctly assigned to the Windows node (ie via kubectl get pods - o wide)

Comment: vpc-admission-webhook-8f77c5d74-nqmmt and vpc-resource-controller-645d6696bc-s5rhk assigned to Linux node. How to fix it?

Comment: Those are supposed to be assigned to Linux nodes. What do their logs look like?  I meant to also check that your test pod is assigned to a Windows node

Answer (score 0):

What is your output for

```
kubectl describe node <windows_node>
```

?

if it's like :

```
  vpc.amazonaws.com/CIDRBlock:           0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/ENI:                 0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address:  0
```

then you need to re-create the nodegroup with different instance type...

then try to deploy this :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: windows-server-iis-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: windows-server-iis-test
      tier: backend
      track: stable
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: windows-server-iis-test
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: windows-server-iis-test
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - powershell.exe
        - -command
        - "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.6/ServiceMonitor.exe' -OutFile 'C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe'; echo '<html><body><br/><br/><marquee><H1>Hello EKS!!!<H1><marquee></body><html>' > C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\default.html; C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe 'w3svc'; "
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 256m
            memory: 256Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 128m
            memory: 100Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: windows-server-iis-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: windows-server-iis-test
    tier: backend
    track: stable
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
kubectl proxy
```

open browser http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/http:windows-server-iis-test:80/proxy/default.html will shown webpage with `Hello EKS` text

Comment: The instance type was m5.large. I removed and re-created the windows group with two different instance types, m1.xlarge and m5.xlarge. But, no luck. I still get   vpc.amazonaws.com/CIDRBlock           0         0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/ENI                 0         0
  vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address  0         0